# MySql Query very slow

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I run the following query on my database :

```
SELECT e.id_dernier_fichier
FROM Enfants e JOIN FichiersEnfants f
ON e.id_dernier_fichier = f.id_fichier_enfant
```

And the query runs fine. If I modifiy the query like this :

```
SELECT e.codega
FROM Enfants e JOIN FichiersEnfants f
ON e.id_dernier_fichier = f.id_fichier_enfant
```

The query becomes very slow ! The problem is I want to select many columns in table e and f, and the query can take up to 1 minute ! I tried different modifications but nothing works. I have indexes on id_* also on e.codega. Enfants has 9000 lines and FichiersEnfants has 20000 lines. Any suggestions ?

Here are the info asked (sorry not having shown them from the beginning) :

[image: Table FichiersEnfants]
[image: Table Enfants]
[image: Index Enfants]
[image: Explain Query 1]
[image: Explain Query 2]

Comment: Is any of those tables actually a view, can you post here the query with the EXPLAIN results.

Comment: table schema ? index definition ? number of records in the table ? mysql version (a little help)? hardware specs ?

Comment: What are the data types of e.codega and e.id_dernier_fichier?

Comment: Post tables structure and the result of explain SELECT e.codega
FROM Enfants e JOIN FichiersEnfants f
ON e.id_dernier_fichier = f.id_fichier_enfant

Comment: @ajreal he did post the number of records (granted he didn't post any of the other essential items you listed)

Comment: Do you have a single index that covers both id_dernier_fichier and codega?  Also, run an update statistics on the tables and see if that improves things.

Comment: I updated my question with all information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference in performance is *possibly* due to `e.id_dernier_fichier` being in the index used for the JOIN, but `e.codega` not being in ***that*** index.

Without a full definition of both tables, and all of their indexes, it's not possible to tell for certain.  Also, including the two EXPLAIN PLANs for the two queries would help.

For now, however, I can elaborate on a couple of things...

If an INDEX is CLUSTERED (this also applies to PRIMARY KEYs), the data is actually physically stored in the order of the INDEX.  This means that knowing you want ***position x*** in the INDEX also implicity means you want ***position x*** in the TABLE.

If the INDEX is not clustered, however, the INDEX is just providing a lookup for you.  Effectively saying ***position x*** in the INDEX corresponds to ***position y*** in the TABLE.

The importance here is when accessing fields not specified in the INDEX.  Doing so means you have to actually go to the TABLE to get the data.  In the case of a CLUSTERED INDEX, you're already there, the overhead of finding that field is pretty low.  If the INDEX isn't clustered, however, you effectifvely have to JOIN the TABLE to the INDEX, then find the field you're interested in.

Note;  Having a composite index on `(id_dernier_fichier, codega)` is very different from having one index on just `(id_dernier_fichier)` and a seperate index on just `(codega)`.

In the case of your query, I don't think you need to change the code at all.  But you *may* benefit from changing the indexes.

You mention that you want to access *many* fields.  Putting all those fields in a composite index is porbably not the best solution.  Instead you may want to create a CLUSTERED INDEX on  `(id_dernier_fichier)`.  This will mean that once the *id_dernier_fichier* has been located, you're already in the right place to get all the other fields as well.

**EDIT** [Note About MySQL and CLUSTERED INDEXes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-index-types.html)

13.2.10.1. Clustered and Secondary Indexes

Every InnoDB table has a special index called the clustered index where the data for the rows is stored:

- If you define a PRIMARY KEY on your table, InnoDB uses it as the clustered index.
- If you do not define a PRIMARY KEY for your table, MySQL picks the first UNIQUE index that has only NOT NULL columns as the primary key and InnoDB uses it as the clustered index.
- If the table has no PRIMARY KEY or suitable UNIQUE index, InnoDB internally generates a hidden clustered index on a synthetic column containing row ID values. The rows are ordered by the ID that InnoDB assigns to the rows in such a table. The row ID is a 6-byte field that increases monotonically as new rows are inserted. Thus, the rows ordered by the row ID are physically in insertion order.

Comment: OP mentioned that both of those fields are indexed.

Comment: Sorry, I have now added all the information in my question. Thanks for helping !

Comment: @jadarnel27 : This is true, but it did not mention if they were separate indexes, compositite indexes, and the lack of EXPLAIN PLAN did not mention which index is in use for those queries.  All of these pieces of information are *critical* to understanding the performance characteristics of the queries.

Comment: @Dems: You're talking about covering index I think. You have no way of telling MySQL if you want to use a clustered index (other than using InnoDB - which uses clustered indexes, or MyISAM - which doesn't)

Comment: @Mchl - I refer to both CLUSTERED and COVERING (Composite) indexes.  Each has different implications on performance for different reasons.

Comment: I use InnoDB. However id_dernier_fichier is not the primary key, so how do I set it as a clustered index ?

Comment: Ok. Just wanted to clarify that. BTW: I wonder how it's possible that `IDX_Enfant_SEXE` created on `SEXE` column - which I assume stores information about child's gender - has a cardinality of 12 ;)

Comment: @Emanuel - If it's not the PRIMARY KEY, it can't be.  Is `id_dernier_fichier` a NOT NULL unique field in that table?

Comment: @Emanuel - Then you can't make that field the table's PRIMARY KEY.  This means that you can only get a performance increase by creating a composite/covering index to include all the fields you are going to select.  This will then mean that the SQL Engine won't have to link back from the INDEX to the TABLE.  It will, however, have the usual overheads of an INDEX : More space used, potential slow down for INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE statements, etc.  It's a balancing act; do you get enough benefit from creating that index?

Comment: It is the only query I have that runs so slow. If it can drammatically improve the speed, and if it does not drammatically decrease the speed of inserts and updates, I think it is worth creating those indexes. But I already created an index that covers all the fields used in the query (IDX_TousLesFous), what do I have to add ?

Comment: That index doesn't include `id_dernier_fichier`.  What you want is the INDEX to accomplish TWO things; make the JOIN as fast as possible AND provide the values of the fields being selected.  That means you need to add `id_dernier_fichier` to that INDEX ***and*** make certain that it's the first field in that index to make the JOIN work.

Comment: I first added `id_dernier_fichier` at the end of my index. I moved it first and now it works ! I will see how my insert and update statements execute but thank you for your help, it works now !

Comment: @Dems let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2277/discussion-between-emanuel-and-dems)