# Mysql SQL query very slow

Tags: mysql, search, many-to-many, query-optimization

[image: DB schema]

I've this schema, And this will sitting on the back of a crawler. `mitza.mine.nu`
I'm not good at SQL, and I came to across close results. but the query 
is running to long. For 2 words takes almost a minute, for`3 forever
on 4555 records`. (current life sample runs another query)

The que  does this:

1. Words from search `w1 w2` hits the DICT and gets the word id's. That's done in a separate
   query.
2. From word id's (`271 and 8596 for example` ) selects all the records and sort them by
   (all records containg both words sorted by weight sum), then word 1 then 2 by weight.

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT(links.linkid),domain.ip,links.linkid,
   links.url,words.weight,words.wordid 
   FROM links 
   JOIN words ON (words.linkid=links.linkid) 
   JOIN domain ON (domain.siteid=links.siteid) 
   WHERE links.linkid IN (SELECT linkid FROM words WHERE wordid=271)
   AND links.linkid IN (SELECT linkid FROM words WHERE wordid=8596)
   ORDER BY words.weight DESC LIMIT 0, 8
   ```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySql Query very slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997411/mysql-query-very-slow)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query, avoiding duplicated calls to links table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(links.linkid),domain.ip,links.linkid,
    links.url,words.weight,words.wordid 
    FROM links 
    JOIN words ON (words.linkid=links.linkid) 
    JOIN domain ON (domain.siteid=links.siteid) 
    WHERE  (words.wordid=271 or words.wordid=8596)
    ORDER BY words.weight DESC LIMIT 0, 8
```

And make sure you have indexes on your primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use inner queries. Also avoid using OR in the where clause as it doesn't uses index. Make an index on wordid, linkid and siteid and try the below query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(links.linkid),domain.ip,links.linkid,
links.url,words.weight,words.wordid 
FROM links 
JOIN words ON (words.linkid=links.linkid) 
JOIN domain ON (domain.siteid=links.siteid) 
WHERE words.wordid  IN (271,8596)
ORDER BY words.weight DESC LIMIT 0, 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(links.linkid),domain.ip,links.linkid,
links.url,words.weight,words.wordid 
    FROM links 
    JOIN 
    (SELECT linkid,weight,wordid FROM words WHERE wordid IN (271,8596)) words 
      ON (words.linkid=links.linkid) 
    JOIN domain 
      ON (domain.siteid=links.siteid) 
ORDER BY words.weight DESC LIMIT 0, 8;
```